# ¿Cómo puedo enviar un archivo XML (o al menos su contenido) a una URL con extensión .ashx desde SoapUI?

Tags: xml, soap, url, soapui, basic

Es prácticamente mi primera vez con el programa SoapUI y me está costando un poco hacer algunas cosas.

La cosa es que lo que tengo que hacer es usando este programa (debe ser este sí o sí) enviar un archivo XML o al menos su contenido a una URL cuya extensión es .ashx (creo entender que esta URL tiene que ver con Visual Basic o algo así, de todas maneras adjunto la URL en concreto más adelante).

Adjunto ahora capturas de la URL, de un trozo del XML que quiero enviar y de lo que he probado yo en SoapUI.

Agradecería mucho vuestra ayuda, gracias.

URL (no sé si a vosotros os dejará entrar, porque creo que requiere certificación o algo así): https://siihacienda.navarra.es/SII_PRUEBAS.proxy/Silicie.ashx

Capturas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas tener un certificado valido para poder realizar esa tarea, sin el es como darte de cabezazos contra una pared.

Comment: ahora lo hemos probado un compañero y yo a la vez ahora ya sí con un certificado que en principio sí es válido e igualmente en el SoapUI me sale igual que como la captura que he subido